# How to fix: Xcode 9 building loop until exit code 255

Tags: xcode

*Please don't mark as duplicate since available threads haven't provided a valid solution.*

Since Xcode 9 one of my projects is stuck in a building loop.

The project is building. Running on iPhone and building again and again. Even builds over and over while coding without asking for build or run.

After cleaning, cleaning build folder, deleting Derived Data and restarting, the project crashes after build with:

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255. The tool may have crashed. Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com with the above output and attach any crash logs for ibtool, ibtoold, Xcode, and Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool created around the time of this failure. These logs can be found in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports or /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.

After several cleaning and restarting, it finally builds and after a couple of more builds and code changes, the whole process restarts. Building stuck in a loop even without asking to build until 255 exit code.

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Same here, I need restart XCode many times during a day! :(

Comment: Seems to be a bug

Comment: Do you maybe have multiple targets in your project? If so, I managed to stop this behaviour by switching off Edit Scheme / Build / Parallelize Build.

Comment: in the project i'm working on in this very minute and experience this exact behavior on physical devices, i have only one target (but i'm using several pods, if that makes any difference)

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, it's just that I've had this behaviour in several projects (they all use multiple pods, i think they all have more than one target too) and this is the first time that I noticed that Xcode was building other targets. Once I switched off Parallelize Build for these other targets - it stopped, i.e. no more repeated building.

Comment: Somebody raised this issue on radar already? Have a radar number?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this issue as well and it has been driving us crazy. The workaround is to set the "IBToolNeverDeque" environment variable to "1", which will modify the behaviour of ibtool and make it much more stable. We have just published a detailed blog post about this particular issue and how we came to find this solution [here](https://blog.devolutions.net/2018/11/insider-series-chasing-down-the-most-annoying-build-system-issue).

One thing which would be nice is finding an easy way to set the environment variable such that it gets set when using Xcode. If possible, set it globally on your system.

Comment: Your proposed solution could be great but you don't ever explain just _how_ to go about setting the IBToolNeverDeque environment variable to "1", neither here, nor in the article you link to.